# Passing string through multiple filters for matching

Tags: r, string, if-statement

Working with MSA data and splitting string then putting them back together. Needing to filter through multiple columns to get strings to match properly. I need to filter the string of cities through states first... I could create a column for each city matched to MSA, but am looking for something more efficient.

```
> testdf <- data.frame(col1 =c('Dallas,Fort Worth,Arlington','Houston,The Woodlands,Sugar Land','Atlanta,Sandy Springs,Roswell'),
+                      col2 =c('TX','TX','GA'))
> df <- data.frame(col1 = c('Arlington','Houston','Arlington','Atlanta'),
+                  col2 = c('TX','TX','VA','GA'),
+                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> testdf
                              col1 col2
1      Dallas,Fort Worth,Arlington   TX
2 Houston,The Woodlands,Sugar Land   TX
3    Atlanta,Sandy Springs,Roswell   GA
> df
       col1 col2
1 Arlington   TX
2   Houston   TX
3 Arlington   VA
4   Atlanta   GA
```

Looking for:

```
     col1 col2  MSA
1 Arlington   TX  Dallas,Fort Worth,Arlington
2   Houston   TX  Houston,The Woodlands,Sugar Land
3 Arlington   VA  NA
4   Atlanta   GA  Atlanta,Sandy Springs,Roswell
```

I'm pretty lost on how to even ask this question, so please let me know if I have a duplicate here. If it is a duplicate, please provide guidance on how to ask better.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but it seems like you want to join two tables, try `dplyr::left_join(testdf ,df,by = "col2")`

Comment: That produces an incorrect result unfortunately, but essentially it is a join, it just needs to be filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
# df to join to
testdf <- data.frame(col1 =c('Dallas,Fort Worth,Arlington','Houston,The Woodlands,Sugar Land','Atlanta,Sandy Springs,Roswell'),
                     col2 =c('TX','TX','GA'),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# combine df's using join and filter by strings
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('Arlington','Houston','Arlington','Atlanta'),
                 col2 = c('TX','TX','VA','GA'),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  left_join(testdf, by="col2") %>%
  set_names(c("city","state","msa")) %>%
  filter(str_detect(msa,city))
  drop_na()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base R to do this:

```
vec = sapply(do.call(paste, c(sep = ".*", df)), grep, do.call(paste, testdf))

transform(df, MSA = testdf[unlist(`is.na<-`(vec, !lengths(vec))), 1])

       col1 col2                              MSA
1 Arlington   TX      Dallas,Fort Worth,Arlington
2   Houston   TX Houston,The Woodlands,Sugar Land
3 Arlington   VA                             <NA>
4   Atlanta   GA    Atlanta,Sandy Springs,Roswell
```

Answer (score -1):

Can use `dplyr` with a tweak to what Yifu mentioned above

`df %>% 
  left_join(testdf %>% 
            dplyr::rename(MSA = col1)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(col1, col2, MSA)`